# how to go to other page when 2 selected of selecbox checked in react?

Tags: reactjs

Here my code:

this `app root` react

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./screen/home/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./screen/about/About'));

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" strict component={ Home }/>
            <Route path="/about" strict component={ About }/>
            <Route path="*" strict component={ () => " 404 Page Not Found " } />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my `render` component return like this

```
render() {
  return(
    <input type="checkbox"
           id="a"
           name="cheker"
           value="a"
           />
           <label for="a">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           id="b"
           name="cheker"
           value="b"
           />
           <label for="b">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           id="c"
           name="cheker"
           value="c"
           />
           <label for="c">A</label>
   )
  }

}
```

my `component` and `handlecheked` like this

```
export default class Home extends Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        postData: [], // i use this for json data
        checked: false,
        isLoading: true
    }
}

handlecheked= () => {
       // this for handle if 2 checked selecbox will go to about page
   }
```

Comment: What is the other page? Is it some route under react router?

Comment: the other page like home/detail

Comment: Ok sure. But first, have you set up your routes? Did you install react router?

Comment: already setup router